# How to add cdn css file to Vue Cli 3 project?

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

I'm trying to include a cdn external css file in my vue-cli-3 project, so I added the css file in the `public/index.html` file like this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mycssfile.css">
```

But the css is not included in the generated `index.html` file. this used to work in vuejs2, I don't understand why it doesn't work with vuejs3. Any idea what the problem is? thanks

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It is simple.
On your main.vue add the following

```html
<style>
  @import "https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css";
</style>
```

Comment: I added it to App.vue instead

Comment: Also thanks for this ! Seems that I was not doing it properly.